# Python-Lookup a cell value in another df, return a boolean value to another cell

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sorting

I am a junior in Python coding. I am having a project to sort an excel file using Python code. There are 3 conditions to sort and the values need to be encoded in any way to sort.
Below are 2 dataframes that I am working on. I need to fill up column "Discount Vendor (True or False)" with boolean value if it found in the 2nd dataframe.

[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]

I searched everywhere and saw many answers about vlookup using pandas.merge, pd.assign, etc. I tried many types but cannot merge into my real excel file.
It is the first time I write on this website. If there is unclear info that make you cannot answer my question, please response so I can give further info.
Appreciate if you could help!
Van
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tya8.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/liTrc.png

Answer (score 0):

I have written this code using nested iteration. Is there a better way to code these statement using differrent methods?
My code as below.

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        if df1.at[i,'Vendor Name']==df2.at[j,'Discount Vendor List']:
            df1.at[i,'Discount Vendor(True/False)']='True'
        else:
            df1.at[i,'Discount Vendor(True/False)']='False'
```